# Setting up multiple rails apps using nginx and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, webserver, puma

I have a web server serving multiple Rails applications using a combination of nginx and Passenger. This is pretty straightforward, because the Passenger install sets-up pretty much everything you need to connect to nginx.

I found "[Rails app with Puma](http://nicolas-brousse.github.io/ubuntu-install-and-tips/pages/installation/rails-puma/)" that seems to explain how to set up nginx and Puma together.  How would this configuration need to be modified in order to serve a second Rails application on the same server?

Also, this guide doesn't say anything about restarting the application automatically if there is a system reboot or some other issue. Is there a way to do that? The nginx + Passenger combo seems to do it by default.

Comment: nginx gets restarted at system boot if the appropriate /etc/init.d file is in place; Without that the system will have no idea that nginx needs starting. You can find samples for that by a quick internet search. The nginx.conf will tell it how to find the rest of the HTTPd stack you want to run.

Comment: I tried this out, and nginx restarts as expected after a reboot. But the Rails application that uses Puma needs to be manually restarted. Is there something I can put in nginx.conf that will restart Puma?

Comment: This post can help you to create an init script for Puma that will be triggered on boot. http://tommy.chheng.com/2013/01/23/deploying-a-rails-app-on-nginxpuma-with-capistrano/

Comment: @Shaun, Did you find the solution. Can you please share with me.